# why does it say that "sleep(1)" is undefined?

Tags: c++, sleep, unistd.h

[here's the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvGr4.png)

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int random = 1 + rand() % 99;
    int user_input;
    int attempts = 1;

    cout << "random = " << random << endl << endl;
    /* delet this line if you dont want spoilers ^^^ */
    do
    {
        cout << "----------| ";
        cout << attempts << " |----------" << "\n";
        attempts++;
        cout << "guess a random number 1 - 100" << endl;
        cin >> user_input;
        cout << endl;

        if (user_input > random || user_input < random)
        {
            cout << "worng try again" << endl;
        }
    } while (user_input < random || user_input > random);

    cout << "you did it!" << endl;
    cout.flush();
    sleep(1);
    cout << "your prize is";
    cout.flush();
    sleep(1);
    cout << ".";
    cout.flush();
    sleep(1);
    cout << ".";
    cout.flush();
    sleep(1);
    cout << "." << endl;
    cout.flush();
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Nothing!";

    return 0;
}
```

I was working on a random number guesser at school, and I was using an online C++ compiler, and it was working completely fine. However, when I moved it over to Visual Studio, it said that 'sleep(1)' is undefined, and I don't know how to fix it.

i tried to change _win34 to _win32 but that didn't work and i cant find any replacement for unistd.h. when i ran the code all i got was the same error

Comment: [std::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: `sleep` is a POSIX function, declared in `unistd.h` header. Windows is not a POSIX system, it doesn't provide such headers. It's own version is called `Sleep`, but it also has different meaning. Your best bet is using C++11 `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, as linked by Paul. If you for whatever reason have to stick to ancient C++, you will have to include Windows and POSIX headers conditionally and use some macro magic to make them look similar.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [This rewrite of your code should compile on any C++14 and above compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/6KPxYnYrT) without needing to do an `#ifdef _WIN32`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your sleep call anyway? I usually avoid sleep bacause having to use it is usually a sign that software design lacks a kind of syncronization mechanism between processes or threads. So only use it if there is no other option to add a syncronization mechanism. In other cases use something like std::condition_variable's wait (so you can abort a wait very quickly if some condition changes during sleep).

Answer (score 1):

The MS UCRT has `_sleep()` for POSIX compatibility, however it has been [deprecated since 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/obsolete-functions?view=msvc-170) in favour of the Windows API `Sleep()` function.

See [Sleep function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) (synchapi.h).

Comment: One subtle difference between unix `sleep` and Win32 `Sleep`. Seconds vs milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answer:

Extend your program to be include this function for Win32

```
#ifdef _WIN32
void sleep(unsigned int seconds) {
    Sleep(seconds * 1000);
}
#end
```